# Convert native null to string "null"

Tags: php, null, isnull

Is it possible to convert `null` to `string` with php?

For instance,

```
$string = null;
```

to

```
$string = "null";
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Am I missing something here?

```
if ($string === null) {
    $string = 'null';
}
```

---

> was thinking something shorter...

You can also use [a ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613595/ternary-operators-in-php):

```
$string = is_null($string) ? 'null' : $string;
```

Your call.

Comment: no u didn't. i just thought there might be a way without using if condition... guess not :-)

Comment: What's the problem with using `if`?

Comment: i think use case for this is only
$str = "ergergegE".($string === null ? "null" : $string)."ergegrregege";
it very long string:)
$str= "regregrege".json_encode($string)."ergegergerge";
is shortest and universally

Comment: @user1303559 Universally? What if $string is anything but null? but a string `STRING` for example? `regregrege"STRING"ergegergerge` IS NOT what one would expect from this expression.

Answer (score 14):

in PHP 7 you can use [Null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) `??`

```
$string = $string ?? 'null';
```

starting from  7.4 you can use [Null coalescing assignment operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.new-features.php#migration74.new-features.core.null-coalescing-assignment-operator) `??=`

```
$string ??= 'null';
```

Note that it will suppress the error message if `$string` doesn't exist. Therefore, it's better to explicitly test the variable with `is_null()`:

```
$string = null;
$string = is_null($string) ? 'null' : $string;    
var_dump($string); // string(4) "null"

$string = 'string';
$string = is_null($string) ? 'null' : $string;    
var_dump($string); // string(6) "string"

$string = null;
$string = is_null($s) ? 'null' : $string;    
var_dump($string); // Warning: Undefined variable $s
```

Answer (score 10):

[var_export](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) can represent any variable in parseable string.

Comment: This answer is WRONG. In case the value is not null it will be CORRUPTED

Comment: It's not wrong, it just covers more than null, it is author role to add specific conditions around it.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($string === null)
{
  $string = "null";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the narrow context where a variable is ONLY `null` and the string/word "null" is desired as printed/visible text, there is nothing ugly/unintuitive about using a null coalescing operator, ternary statement, or a comparatively verbose verbose `if`. Just be sure to encapsulate your logic with parentheses if you are concatenating the value to another string.

Conversely, using a native function call on an unconditionally `null` value:

- will be less intuitive for a human who is less acquainted with the technique,
- less performant, but not noticeably so -- unless you are doing something in the magnitude of millions of times,
- will have its own unique behavior dictating whether to print `NULL` or `null`,
- in the case of `var_dump()`, a newline is appended to the printed value.

Here are a battery of solution candidates and their output when fed `null` as input: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/vWVSW))

```
$null = null;

echo 'var_export(): ' . var_export($null, true);

echo "\n";

echo 'var_dump(): ' . (function($v){ ob_start(); var_dump($v); return ob_get_clean(); })($null);

//echo "\n";

echo 'print_r(): ' . print_r($null, true);

echo "\n";

echo 'json_encode(): ' . json_encode($null);

echo "\n";

echo 'serialize(): ' . serialize($null);

echo "\n";

echo 'strval(): ' . strval($null);

echo "\n";

echo 'gettype(): ' . gettype($null);

echo "\n";

echo 'null coalesce: ' . ($null ?? 'null');

echo "\n";

echo 'ternary: ' . ($null === null ? 'null' : $null);

echo "\n";

echo 'condition: ' .  (function($v) { if ($v === null) { return 'null'; }})($null);
```

Output:

```
var_export(): NULL
var_dump(): NULL
print_r(): 
json_encode(): null
serialize(): N;
strval(): 
gettype(): NULL
null coalesce: null
ternary: null
condition: null
```

As an extension of the scope of the question, using native functions to convert non-string-type data to printable text:

- may be ideal if the values have a limited range of possibilities (e.g. nullable boolean values are very well suited to the use of `json_encode()`,
- may result in value mutation due to truncation, encoding rules, or even excess characters relating to the value's metadata.

Ultimately, my advice is to use the null coalescing operator (because it is intuitive/self-documenting, concise, and most performant) unless you have a compelling reason to do otherwise.

Answer (score -3):

it has best solution:

```
$var = null;
$stringNull = json_encode($var);
```

you can test it as

```
$var = null;
$stringNull = json_encode($var);
$null = json_decode($stringNull, true);
var_dump($stringNull);
var_dump($null);
```

Comment: Seem to be the slowest and overcomplicated

Comment: It's neither slowest nor overcomplicated. It's just incorrect. Nobody wants their string `string` to become `"string"` with quotes.